# getopts doesn't work when there are arguments before options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

When I run the command like this :

**`$: ./script -r f1 f2`**  :
it detects the "-r" flag and sets the recursive flag to 1.

**`$: ./script directory/  -r`**  :
`getopts` doesn't detect the `-r` flag at all. So inside the case statement it never detects `-r` flag and so the while loop doens't even run at all. how to fix this ?

```
RECURSIVE_FLAG=0
while getopts ":rR" opt ; do
    echo " opt = $opt"
    set -x
    case "$opt" in 

        r) RECURSIVE_FLAG=1 ;;
        R) RECURSIVE_FLAG=1 ;;
        :)echo "not working" ;;
        *)echo "Testing *" ;;

    esac
done
```

Comment: Options are supposed to be before filenames. A word with a `/` in it looks like a filename.

Comment: Try `./script -r directory/`

Comment: @Barmar thats not the issue . I am trying to make a command like utility , so i want to make it work for those cases I mentioned too. How to fix that ? I want to mimic the "rm" command say. That handles the options after filenames too right ?

Comment: GNU `rm` does, BSD/macOS `rm` doesn't.  POSIX guidelines say that options should come before operands, and POSIX `getopts` is required to follow that.

Comment: @Nateshbhat It depends on the version of `rm` -- gnu utilities mostly allow options anywhere in the arg list (except after `--`), but non-gnu ones often don't. But `getopts` only works with options at the beginning of the argument list (well, unless you do something weird around it...). So if you want to use `getopts`, you should probably stick to options first.

Comment: I tried your script the first way and it didn't set the recursive flag to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with slash. `getopts` stops processing options when it gets to the first argument that doesn't begin with `-`. This is the [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts) behavior:

> When the end of options is encountered, `getopts` exits with a return value greater than zero. `OPTIND` is set to the index of the first non-option argument, and *name* is set to `?`.

Your claim that it works when you use

```
./script f1 f2 -r
```

is simply wrong. I added `echo $RECURSIVE_FLAG` to the end of your script, and when I ran it that way it echoed `0`.

If you want to allow a more liberal syntax, with options after filenames (like GNU `rm`) you'll need to do some argument parsing of your own. Put your `getopts` loop inside another loop. When the `getopts` loop finishes, you can do:

```
# Find next option argument
while [[ $OPTIND <= $# && ${!OPTIND} != -* ]]; do
    ((OPTIND++))
done
# Stop when we've run out of arguments
if [[ $OPTIND > $# ]]; then
    break
fi
```